# Nested ViewPager React Native 0.50

Tags: javascript, android-viewpager, react-native

---

I want to achieve a home page works like the Instagram's (app), you know, the upper tab indicator and the lower center navigation. I don't know if this is the right approach, but i decided to place a view pager inside a view pager.

Turns out, I've always got a blank screen on the child view pager, even though I've placed the flex:1 on the wrapper element, its still don't display a thing!

```
<ViewPagerAndroid>
    <View key="1">
        a
    </View>
    <View key="2">
        <ViewPagerAndroid>
            <View key="1">
                <ListView A/>
            </View>
            <View key="2">
                <ListView B/>
            </View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
    </View>
    <View>
        c
    </View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

i did some googling and i found guys with the same problem, I've tried the solution but its not working.

1. [One](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1442)
2. [Two](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8348)

I did some debugging, in the view wrapper of the inner View Pager if i place some text, its displayed.

```
<ViewPagerAndroid>
    ...
    <View key="2">
        <Text>Test, and this is displayed on the screen</Text>
        <ViewPagerAndroid>
            <View style={styles.pageStyle} key="1">
                <ListView/>
            </View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
    </View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

It almost like that the inner view Pager is never rendered.

or should i just replace the parent view pager with a standard separate component and connect it with react navigation?

Comment: Mate any news on that.
I think i encountered the same problem with react-navigation inside a view pager. I get a blank page :(

Comment: Didn't find any solution. so i scrapped the code and placed whole different structure. No longer using the viewPager, so i used traditional navigation thing.